# Regex validation for server for samples like 10.10.10.10 and smtp.reliance-retail.com

Tags: html, angularjs, regex

I have regex validation for accepting servers

```
ng-pattern="/^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[.]([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[.]([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[.]([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/" required>
```

Can you help me , how to include the validation for "smtp.reliance-retail.com" type servers with an 'OR' condition in the regex.                            #Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you try to add it after an `|`?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly you want a regex to validate both ip addresses and hostnames?

Comment: yes @ManosPasgiannis If you can , please do share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to validate ip addresses

```
^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$
```

and this one to validate hostnames

```
^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$
```

Or you can combine these two in a single regex

```
(^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$)|(^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$)
```

Comment: Actually it works. In case you missed, I have not included in my answer the slashes at the start and end of the regex. Try to add them and test again.

Comment: @Fayazshaik Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.